# Creating a new Dictionary in a SOAP Envelope

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

Pretty basic question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

How do you specify a new instance of a `Dictionary<string, string>` in SOAP? Basically I have this envelope (ommitted envelope top level tag for readability):

```
<soapenv:Body>
   <tem:LogInWithCredentials>      
       <tem:Request>             
       <ttf1:Password>password</ttf1:Password>         
       <ttf1:UserName>username</ttf1:UserName>
       <ttf1:RequestInfo></ttf1:RequestInfo>
      </tem:Request>      
   </tem:LogInWithCredentials>
</soapenv:Body>
```

`RequestInfo` is the property in question, but it's always `null`. I assumed that just the presence of the property in the envelope would be deserialized into an empty `Dictionary<string, string>`, however this is not the case.

Comment: Traditionally, dictionaries are not serializable in .NET. That said, DataContractSerializer can handle this without a problem. I suspect your problem is not the serializer.

Comment: What's your reason for thinking that would be deserialized as a dictionary? How is it defined in the schema? And, did you try using a Service Reference? In that case, what is the type of the generated property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @flem says, the DataContractSerializer might provide the clues needed to answer this. Serializing an empty dictionary gives the following XML. Give that a try in your RequestInfo element and see if it works (I've not tested it myself).

```
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? If it doesn't work then I'll update the answer accordingly.